# Log4net or azure for logging azure websites

Tags: c#, azure, logging, log4net

I have a scenario where I have to implement logging for website deployed in azure. What would be the best option to implement logging? would it be best to leverage logging options from azure portal or use log4net or use both log4net and azure inbuilt options? If I were you what would you suggest as a best practice? Any cons with log4net over Azure logging options?

Comment: Check out stackify - we just started using it and it's way better than other implementations.

Comment: This is an opinion/tool recommendation question, with no right answer, just discussion. Off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use log4net. There are plugins for Azure Application Insights and for Stackify, along with other options that can be configured. It allows you to abstract where the logs are going from the code and makes it easy to change location later.